# MongoDB query nested array

Tags: regex, mongodb, database-design, schema

I have some documents in MongoDB with tables inside like the following:

```
                           doc 1                            
 __________________________    __________________________   
|          Table 1a        |  |          Table 1b        |  
| apples | bananas | pears |  | apples | bananas | pears |  
|--------|---------|-------|  |--------|---------|-------|  
|    1   |    2    |   3   |  |    1   |    5    |   3   |  
|    4   |    5    |   6   |  |    2   |    4    |   6   |  
|    7   |    8    |   9   |  |    1   |    9    |   6   |  
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾    ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾   

                           doc 2                            
 __________________________    __________________________   
|          Table 2a        |  |          Table 2b        |  
| apples | bananas | pears |  | apples | bananas | pears |  
|--------|---------|-------|  |--------|---------|-------|  
|    5   |    2    |   7   |  |    1   |    6    |   5   |  
|    4   |    4    |   1   |  |    7   |    2    |   4   |  
|    3   |    9    |   8   |  |    8   |    9    |   3   |  
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾    ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

which I represented in MongoDB with the following structure:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "doc 1",
    "tables": [
      {
        "name": "table a",
        "lines": [
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "4"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "5"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "6"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "7"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "8"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "9"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "table b",
        "lines": [
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "5"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "4"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "6"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "9"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "6"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "doc 2",
    "tables": [
      {
        "name": "table a",
        "lines": [
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "5"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "7"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "4"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "4"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "3"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "9"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "8"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "table b",
        "lines": [
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "1"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "6"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "5"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "7"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "4"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key_values": [
              {
                "key": "apples",
                "value": "8"
              },
              {
                "key": "bananas",
                "value": "9"
              },
              {
                "key": "pears",
                "value": "3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to query documents by table content, for example, finding the document with table that has `apples==1 && pears==3` appearing on the same line, which in this case should match `doc 1` as `table 1a` and `table 1b` are a match (while `table 2b` is not a match as `apples==1` and `pears==3` do not appear on the same line)

I understand how to query for a key-value,

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "tables.lines": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "key_values": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "key": "key_a_1",
              "value": "value_a_1_1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

however I am not sure how to take this one step further to look on the same line. Also, I would like to match using regular expressions, i.e. search for `bana` rather than specifying the full text `banana`.

Is this even possible?

I also created an [example in the Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eM22_GXYTdm)

Comment: It sounds like there is only 1 mongodb document and within the one document, there are multiple tables. And within each table there are multiple lines.  When querying for `apples==1 && bananas==2`, should the result contain the full `table a` or just the **line** within `table a` with `apple=1 & bananas = 2 & pears = 3`?

Comment: You can try using [Aggregation Array Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#array-expression-operators).

Comment: For brevity I included only one document in the question, however in reality there are more documents (also in the Mongo Playground).

Ideally I would want to return the entire document. Returning only the table is OK too